# How can I get input fields names from a string with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have some form in a variable. I have some input fields with names. How can I get all name="" from that string?

Now I'm trying this:

```
 preg_match_all ('/(name="(.*?"))\d/s', $ki, $matches1);
```

But not working well. It gives me just a few and it gives me a lots of unnececary informations.

Comment: what's wrong with this? `preg_match_all('/(name="(.*?)")\d/s', $ki, $matches1);` or `preg_match_all('/name="(.*?)"(?=\d)/s', $ki, $matches1);`

Comment: try `"([^"]*)"` instead of `"(.*?")`

Comment: Unless you have form element names with newlines in them (eg. `name="herp\nderp"`) then you don't need the `s` modifier.

Comment: Why not just get array_keys() on $_GET or $_POST (depending how you submit the form)?

Comment: I have them in statics HTML files those made static. There are a lots of, its easier if I can just get all inputs names.  `preg_match_all ('/(name="([^"]*))\d/s', $ki, $matches1);` gives me a few images name, but doesnt gives me the input names.

Comment: As vks said, you need to post your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex:

```
preg_match_all( '/name\s*=\s*(?|"(.*?)"|\'(.*?)\')/', $ki, $matches1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using array.

i.e. By using explode method

```
        $content='name="name1" other example text  name="name2" other example text  name="name3" ';         

        $finalResult=array();

        function getBetweenAll($content,$start,$end)
        {   
            $res = explode($start , $content , 2);

            if(isset($res[1]) && $res[1]!='' )
            {
                $value = explode($end , $res[1] , 2);        

                global $finalResult;
                $finalResult[]=$value[0];     

                if(isset($value[1]) && $value[1]!='')
                {
                    $content=$value[1];
                    getBetweenAll($content,$start,$end);
                }
            }      
        }

        $start='name="';
        $end='"';
        getBetweenAll($content,$start,$end);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($finalResult);
        echo "</pre>";
```